# Gptcache and streaming are incompatible

Tags: django, caching, chatbot, langchain

Now, I have made a chatbot which can stream and answer the question from user.
However that chatbot can't stream showing no error in terminal after I implemented init_cache() and changed llm.
Here are some parts of my code:

```
class CustomStreamingCallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    """Callback Handler that Stream LLM response."""

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
 
        
    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """Run on new LLM token. Only available when streaming is enabled."""
        self.queue.put(token)

def generate_stream(q: Queue, job_done):
    while (...):
        try:
            stream = q.get(True, timeout=1)
            print(stream)
            yield stream
        except:
            continue


def openai_response_generator(queue, retriever, prompt, query, chat_history, job_done):
    
    llm = LangChainChat(
        chat=ChatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
            streaming=True,
            temperature=0,
            callbacks=([CustomStreamingCallbackHandler(queue)]),
    ))

    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=llm,
            retriever=retriever,
            condense_question_prompt=prompt,
            return_source_documents=True,
            )
    
 
    res = chain({'question': query, 'chat_history': chat_history})
    print(res["answer"])
    queue.put(job_done)


def get_content_func(data, **_):
    return data.get("messages")[-1].content
   

def init_cache():
    onnx = Onnx()
    cache_base = CacheBase('sqlite')
    vector_base = VectorBase('faiss',dimension=onnx.dimension, collection_name='for_cache')
    data_manager = get_data_manager(cache_base, vector_base)
    cache.init(
        pre_embedding_func=get_content_func,
        embedding_func=onnx.to_embeddings,
        data_manager=data_manager,
        similarity_evaluation=SearchDistanceEvaluation(max_distance=1),
    )
    cache.set_openai_key()
    # save data to cache from getting one answer
    cache.config.auto_flush = 1

init_cache()
task = threading.Thread(
            target=openai_response_generator,
            args=(queue, retriever, prompt, query, chat_history, job_done)
        )
task.start()
```

Before I changed llm, it was:

```
llm = chatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
            streaming=True,
            temperature=0,
            callbacks=([CustomStreamingCallbackHandler(queue)]),
    )
```

Could you help me with that?

I have already tried to change the chain and llm but it still can't stream.